# Azure DocumentDB generic client

Tags: windows, database-browser

I would like a Windows client to see/query/update my Azure-DocumentDB database.

We should do that online using https://portal.azure.com/
But since this service is down now I have no way to update my data simply.

Does exist a stand-alone generic application that let end-user to query/update documentDB items ?

(For example, an equivalent exists for Azure service bus Topic/Queue with "Azure Service bus Explorer")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentDB Studio (Windows-only) is a standalone explorer.

Github repo [here](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio).

With this, you'll be able to explore users, data, associated triggers/UDFs/etc. For example, here's a snippet from one of my data collections:

[image: docdb studio screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, This application do the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Mongo Chef**, which is perfectly compatible with our document db. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-mongochef

[image: Use Mongo Chef to access document DB]